# Laravel Eloquent VS DB handler

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

What is the main difference between Eloquent and DB handler query? Does eloquent works faster?

Comment: Eloquent is an ORM(Object Relational Mapper), which extends the functionality the PDO or mysqli.

It is slower to use and ORM, but it improves code readability and maintainabilty as it allowes you to work with database tables and registries in a OO way

Comment: so should I use Query Builder if I want better performance?

Comment: The difference is so little that a I Would always recomend to use an ORM, you can allways use RAW sql queries in an ORM if you need to. ORM will make your project easier to mantain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of speed Query Builder is faster than Eloquent ORM. But ORM is easier to use. ORM is popular for its readability and maintainability. To know more, you can checkout this article: https://blog.sriraman.in/laravel-eloquent-vs-fluent-query-builder/

Comment: Thanks  bro, I just read that Article and it is nice, I'll try example in it.

Comment: How can I test which query is taking more time, I have an API in L5 but the same code for web app in CI is working faster, how can I check it? I used lumen 5 for API.

Comment: here is a trick how you can do that: 
`$before = microtime(true);
/*code you execute*/
$after = microtime(true);
echo ($after-$before)/$i . " sec\n";`
Dot forget to approve my answer.

Comment: what is $i here? echo ($after-$before)/$i . " sec\n";

Comment: Ops, it should be `echo ($after-$before). " sec\n";`